# How to force all words that overflow a line to wrap to the next line?

Tags: html, css, overflow, word-wrap

My document width is set to `100vw` and is responsive to changes in the size of the viewport.

Well, almost. It happens that some words overflow, but do not get pushed to the next line. This creates a small horizontal scroll:

[image]

When slightly reducing the width of the browser, the word (`tremit`) is pushed to the next line.

It seems to me that there is some kind of weight applied to the word wrapping, of the kind *"up to this overflow keep the word on the line, and if above then wrap it"*.

First question: is this supposition correct?

If so: **is there a way to reduce that weight to zero, that is to force a word to be wrapped whenever it overflows?**

I thought that [`overflow-wrap: anywhere;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap) would be the solution, but adding it to `<body>` does not change anything:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    font-size: 150%;
    width: 100vw;
    overflow-wrap: anywhere;
}
```

Comment: you don't need width:100vw since the body is already full width and 100vw include the scrollbar width so you will always have unexpected overflow

Comment: for word-barking your could use css property: `word-break: break-word`

Comment: @FoxPro: I do not want to break words, I want to break lines.

Comment: @TemaniAfif: do you mean that I should remove the `width` in the body (because it is redundant), and manually account for the scrollbar width? (the vertical one, the one on the right of the browser) (→ by setting a width slightly smaller than 100vw?)

Comment: @WoJ BY default the body will take all available width as in `width:100%` that width doesn't include the vertical scrollbar if it exists, On the other hand `100vw` does include the scrollbar no matter what, so there will always be words cut off like that. You don't have to manually do anything about it.

Comment: simply remove the width and do nothing, the default behavior is what you want (the scrollbar with is considered)

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you misunderstood the issue you are facing. There is no wrong with the word wrapping, but user-agent adds some default margin to body. Mostly we won't add text directly to `body`. So I removed the default margin and added padding instead. Please check my sample code. I guess word wrapping happens naturally & there is no horizontal scroll. Demo [here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GEEFJ3J6NSEF).

```css
*{
box-sizing:border-box;
}

body{
width:100%;
margin:0;
padding:8px;
}
```

```html
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
```